# Can we export and import Janus graph using the same vertex ID?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server, janus

I am trying to export and import a graph using Gryo Reader/Writer. I am using the below commands on gremlin console.

Old Schema :

```
final Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
graph.io(IoCore.gryo()).writeGraph("tinkerpop-modern.kryo");
```

New Schema :

```
final Graph newGraph = TinkerGraph.open();
newGraph.io(IoCore.gryo()).readGraph("tinkerpop-modern.kryo");
```

I am able to import the same count of data in a new schema but the only problem I am facing is the vertex Ids of the new imported data are changing every time and not the same as the exported graph data.

In my case, I have a dev graph with many vertices that I'd like to export to some other graph and use the same ID as in the previous graph so it is sort of like "static" ID

Is there a way I can import the same graph data with the same vertex ids ?

Please advise.

Comment: It's not clear from the example in your question and the tags you used which graph database you are seeing the problem with. Are you using JanusGraph or TinkerGraph for the dev graph you mention later in the question?

Comment: If you are using JanusGraph then by default it does not allow you to load and keep user defined IDs. They will get re-mapped during the load.